# Why ajax blur event not triggered?

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to update the message with the value in promoField on lost focus , but the ajax call does not seem to be firing, any ideas?

```
<h:inputText   id="promoField" value="PromoCode99"  maxlength="255" style=" width : 210px;">
<f:ajax event="blur" render="outpromotext" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="outpromotext" for="promoField" />
```

Comment: Look in browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor and JS console. What step exactly fails? Is there no HTTP request at all? Or is the HTTP response unexpected? Or is there a JS error?

Comment: I don't see anything failing, the call is made and return a 200 OK.

Comment: Here is the RESPONSE : <partial-response><changes><update id="signupControls:j_idt19:j_idt20:outpromotext"><![CDATA[<span id="signupControls:j_idt19:j_idt20:outpromotext"></span>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[4777383520883332609:5012052109187607487]]></update></changes></partial-response>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. There is no validation error in your case. The message will be displayed only if a message exist in first place.

Change your code to this and check the result:

```
        <h:inputText   id="promoField" value=""  maxlength="255" required="true" style=" width : 210px;">
            <f:ajax event="blur"  render="outpromotext" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="outpromotext" for="promoField" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think h:message is intended only for displaying error messages.